Gazebo SDF UAV model bug
I am trying to make transwing UAV model to be simulated into Gazebo with ROS2, I used phobos plugin in blender to do such a thing, the Blender version I used is 3.3, I am using gazebo 11, with ros2 humble. The uav can transition from VTOL to the fixed wing mode by rotating the wings in two dimensions, I have implemented the links tree, joints, collisions, and inertials, and the UAV is looking exactly how it should look in rviz:

I tried moving the joints, and they move exactly how they were set back phobos, blender. Additionally I have also set all the max efforts and max velocities for each joint in the whole urdf. I used phobos to generate the SDF and the URDF both at the same time, the SDF when displayed in gazebo, the wings start dancing manically the moment it spawns onto Gazebo, here is a clip, at the beginning the simulation was paused, then continued after the uav was placed, GIF image is too big to uploaded in stackexchange
Why does such a thing happen? What are the possible solutions? The SDF you just saw was generated from Phobos, BUT interestingly enough, when I took the URDF from Phobos and converted it into SDF using this command from gazebo: "gz sdf -p uav.urdf > uav.sdf", the outputted sdf did not include both of the wings, they were just omitted as if they never existed in the urdf, most likely it is the same reason that made the sdf from phobos misbehave in gazebo. The wings start with two links, the first is an empty link that only has a joint to rotate in the x axis, the second link which is a child of the first contains the collisions, visuals and everything else in the wing and has a joint to rotate in the y axis, both links are exactly on top of each other.
To minimize confusion, the first picture is the UAV in vtol, after the wings' both joints rotate, they should like 
I have also run gazebo in verbose mode, and I received these four errors regarding the continuous joints that represent the propellers, I checked them out and nothing was wrong, I converted them to revolute joints and the errors disappeared but the model kept glitching, there is also another error that keeps appearing which is shown at the beginning:
Error [Converter.cc:113] Unable to convert from SDF version 1.9 to 1.7
Error [Converter.cc:113] Unable to convert from SDF version 1.9 to 1.7
[Err] [ODEPhysics.cc:904] EXCEPTION: Unable to create joint of type[continuous]

[Err] [Model.cc:272] LoadJoint Failed
[Err] [ODEPhysics.cc:904] EXCEPTION: Unable to create joint of type[continuous]

[Err] [Model.cc:272] LoadJoint Failed
[Err] [ODEPhysics.cc:904] EXCEPTION: Unable to create joint of type[continuous]

[Err] [Model.cc:272] LoadJoint Failed
[Err] [ODEPhysics.cc:904] EXCEPTION: Unable to create joint of type[continuous]

[Err] [Model.cc:272] LoadJoint Failed

I have tweaked the gazebo command conversion to make the sdf version to 1.7, the command becomes "gz sdf -v 1.7 -p uav.urdf > uav.sdf", but the main issue still persists while converting urdf to sdf through gazebo, it still excludes the wings links, here is the full sdf file generated from Phobos here, the body characters limit is exceeded thus I cant display the sdf content directly here,

The first thing to check is that you have appropriate moments of inertia (<inertial> tag) defined. The defaults may very bad for your situation.
